# magnific popup + gravity form query string not passing

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, query-string

I am using [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) to display a gravity from in a popup.
the form is on the page using this code:

```
<div id="form" class="contact-popup mfp-hide">[gravityform id=1]</div>
```

and my magnific pop JS is like so:

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true,
  mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
});});
```

This works perfectly with:

`<a class="buttongrp left open-popup-link" href="#form">Book Now</a>`

However if i add a query string to the link:

```
<a class="buttongrp left open-popup-link" href="#form/?tripcode=test">Book Now</a>
```

the poppup stop working and of course the data is not passed into the form.

Does any one have any idea how to dynamically populate a gravity from in a popup from a query string in the link?

Note that if the form is on a separate page, the query string does work.

Thank you

Comment: This is not really a wp issue, but if the magnific pop stops working when you change the href, then there must be a js error somewhere, or magnific pop up required a specific href attribute. Look for js errors first.